# How to find the zeroes of a cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to find the zeroes of
$8p^3-6p-1$, which are either in surd form or integers (strictly positive). Any to help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid the roots are very "ugly" and they are decidedly not integers. A good way to see if the roots are integers is to try factors of the constant term.

Comment: @yanbo One of the roots is apparently $\cos\frac{\pi}{9}$. Probably the other two also have nice forms

Comment: But the OP wants it in surds, and $\cos(\pi/9)$ does not give a nice surd form. But you are right!

Comment: As $\cos3y=4\cos^3y-3\cos y,$

putting  $p=\cos y,$ we get $2\cos3y-1=0\implies \cos3y=\frac12=\cos\frac\pi3$

$$\implies 3y=2n\pi\pm \frac\pi3$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\implies y=\frac{6n\pm1}9\pi$$ where $n=0,1,2$

Comment: Am trying to find in surd form the value of Cos20

Answer (score 0):

You can find the exact expressions using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8p%5E3-6p-1=0), which gives
$$p = -\frac14 \left(1-i \sqrt3\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac12 (1+i \sqrt3)}-\frac12 \left(\frac12 (1+i \sqrt3)\right)^{2/3}$$
as one of the roots (Yes, there are imaginary terms in it, but the result is real)